# how can i get a duration of audio after converted by Google Cloud Speech-to-Text

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I'm using Google Cloud Speech-to-Text in my project.

The problem is i want to get the duration of audio from the response for pricing calculation.

I'm using nodejs and here what i got

```
LongRunningRecognizeMetadata {
  progressPercent: 100,
  startTime:
   Timestamp {
     seconds: Long { low: 1529041397, high: 0, unsigned: false },
     nanos: 352339000 },
  lastUpdateTime:
   Timestamp {
     seconds: Long { low: 1529041404, high: 0, unsigned: false },
     nanos: 505193000 } }
```

Is that startTime and lastUpdateTime is the duration of audio
Or the lastUpdateTime is the last time that speech be converted (after that, audio still continues but nothing on it)?

I can check it by my self but i can't convert the time in startTime and lastUpdateTime to datetime format.

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Digging in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/LongRunningRecognizeMetadata) I found this:

> startTime : Time when the request was received. string (Timestamp
>   format)
>
> lastUpdateTime : Time of the most recent processing update. string
>   (Timestamp format)

You can read an explanation about how Timestamp format works [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#timestamp).

Knowing this you can convert Timestamp to Date in many ways (with your own code, using an [online calculator](https://www.epochconverter.com/), etc)

Comment: But on my first question, Is there anyway to know the real duration of audio file?
I want to know the duration of my file from response for pricing calculation. I will continue digging in the documentation but if u know？

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/pricing) pricing is based on the amount of audio successfully processed by the service, rounded up to increments of 15 seconds. This means if you do a request with an audio with duration of 16 seconds you will be charged for a duration of 30 seconds which is 0.012 USD (for non video speech recognition) if you already exceeded the [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/pricing#pricing_table).

**To sum up, you will be charged for the duration of an audio that you are sending to the request.**

There is a way to get a duration of each recognized word with [`WordInfo`](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/speech/recognize#WordInfo).